# Including png in several layer with ocgx for making a pdf

Tags: pdftex, pdf, ocg

I try to make a pdf with pdflatex, which should contains several pngs images. The special thing is, that there should be for each png one layer (ocgx).
At the end I want to have a pdf file, which all these pngs on one page, which can be activated or not.
But my problem is, that I get for each png a new page.
Further I get for every page the page number and I don't know why, but I did not do that. 
Does anybody have a idea?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}

\begin{ocg}{1}{1}{1}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{a.png} \par
\end{ocg}

\begin{ocg}{1}{2}{1}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{b.png} \par
\end{ocg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try with `\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{b.png}` or `\includegraphics[height=LENGTH]{b.png}`

Comment: I mean, may be images are of large size and one need to reduce it.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \setocgs{ocg1 ocg2 ocg3}{ocg1}{ocg2 ocg3}{A-PNG}
\item \setocgs{ocg1 ocg2 ocg3}{ocg2}{ocg1 ocg3}{B-PNG}
\item \setocgs{ocg1 ocg2 ocg3}{ocg3}{ocg1 ocg2}{C-PNG}
\end{enumerate}

\providecommand{\pica}[1]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.125]{#1.png}%
}


\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[] (p1) {\pica{A}};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{ocg}
\begin{ocg}{OCG 2}{ocg2}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[] (p1) {\pica{B}};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{ocg}
\begin{ocg}{OCG 3}{ocg3}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[] (p1) {\pica{C}};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{ocg}


\end{document}
```

You should not activate each figure (which is the last parameter, 0 or 1). Your example both figures are at 1 and then both will be displayed...

Comment: So this requires the use of TikZ to put the pictures in the nodes? It can't possibly make sense to use `\centering` inside the `tikzpicture` can it? What is that supposed to do?

Comment: You are absolutely right.